# Cloudwatch event rule to match branch pattern name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to trigger a CodePipeline Build when someone makes a commit to an AWS Codecommit branch. This works if I target the master branch with a pattern like this:

```json
{
  "detail": {
    "referenceName": ["master"],
    "referenceType": ["branch"]
  },
  "detail-type": ["CodeCommit Repository State Change"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:codecommit:region:1234:repo-name"],
  "source": ["aws.codecommit"]
}
```

But it does not work when I try to match any branch that starts with the "release" string, as per documentation from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#filtering-prefix-matching):

```json
{
  "detail": {
    "referenceName": [{
      "prefix": "release/"
    }],
    "referenceType": ["branch"]
  },
  "detail-type": ["CodeCommit Repository State Change"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:codecommit:region:1234:repo-name"],
  "source": ["aws.codecommit"]
}
```

Is there another way I can match a branch with a pattern name?

Comment: The filter pattern is OK.  Is the event firing? Check the invocation metrics in Rule>Monitoring in the EventBridge console.